# Is there an R function to mutate a dataframe and create a new dataframe based on the following conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
   1.   2.   3.   4.    5. 
R1 NA  881.  950  981.  1000
R2 650 760.  890. NA.   NA
R3 743 834.  960. 1001. 1115
```

I want to mutate the dataframe and create a new dataframe that keeps only the minimum value of each row, all my unwanted values would return as NA, for an output of something like this:

```
   1.   2.   3.   4.    5. 
R1 NA  881   NA   NA    NA
R2 650  NA   NA   NA    NA
R3 743  NA   NA   NA    NA
```

---

`dput`:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(NA, 650L, 743L), V2 = c(881L, 760L, 834L
), V3 = c(950L, 890L, 960L), V4 = c(981L, NA, 1001L), V5 = c(1000L, 
NA, 1115L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the data, `dput(my_data)`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in base R:

```
t(apply(your_data, 1, \(v) { is.na(v) <- -which.min(v); return(v) }))
```

This uses the `is.na<-` assigment, which sets NA values based on index. `-which.max(v)` everthing except the **first** minimum value.

Gives:

> ```
>       V1  V2 V3 V4 V5
> [1,]  NA 881 NA NA NA
> [2,] 650  NA NA NA NA
> [3,] 743  NA NA NA NA
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
df* NA^(col(df) != max.col(-replace(df, is.na(df), Inf)))

    X1  X2 X3 X4 X5
R1  NA 881 NA NA NA
R2 650  NA NA NA NA
R3 743  NA NA NA NA
```

---

```
t(apply(df, 1, \(x) ifelse(x == min(x, na.rm = TRUE), x, NA)))
    X1  X2 X3 X4 X5
R1  NA 881 NA NA NA
R2 650  NA NA NA NA
R3 743  NA NA NA NA
```